# XQuery SQL Server performing so slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have quite a big query which has a lot of joins and also a lot of xquery lookups. Now my query gives  me result after about 45s, which is unacceptable. However if i  remove the xquery it's only 5s. So I'm wondering how I can speed up these xqueries.

Here's my sql (keep in mind that the 3dots are referring to similar repitions):

```
SET ARITHABORT ON;
with Case_Entries as (
select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [Case].[Id] Desc) as DataRow, --needed for pagination
[Case].[RefNumber] as Case_RefNumber,
...
[Case].[DateOfArrival] as Case_DateOfArrival,
[Case].[WhoUpdate] as Case_WhoUpdate,
[Surgeon].[FirstName] as Case_Surgeon,
[Status].[Description] as Case_Status,
TravelCompanionSalutation.PropertyValuesXml.value('(/PDS/PD[PN="Title"]/PTS[C="en"]/V)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Case_TravelCompanionSalutation,
RequestedProcedure1.PropertyValuesXml.value('(/PDS/PD[PN="Name"]/PTS[C="en"]/V)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Case_RequestedProcedure1,
RequestedProcedure2.PropertyValuesXml.value('(/PDS/PD[PN="Name"]/PTS[C="en"]/V)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Case_RequestedProcedure2,
...
FamilyAsthma.PropertyValuesXml.value('(/PDS/PD[PN="Answer"]/PTS[C="en"]/V)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Case_FamilyAsthma,
FamilyCancer.PropertyValuesXml.value('(/PDS/PD[PN="Answer"]/PTS[C="en"]/V)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Case_FamilyCancer,
'' + [ContactName].[FirstName] + ' ' + [ContactName].[LastName] + '' as Case_ContactName,
[AssignedTo].[FirstName] as Case_AssignedTo
from [Case] with(nolock)
left outer join [UserSettings] as Surgeon with(nolock) on  [Case].[SurgeonId]=[Surgeon].[Id]
left outer join [WorkflowDefinition] as Status with(nolock) on  [Case].[StatusId]=[Status].[Id]
left outer join [Lookup] as TravelCompanionSalutation with(nolock) on  [Case].[TravelCompanionSalutationId]=[TravelCompanionSalutation].[Id]
left outer join [Lookup] as RequestedProcedure1 with(nolock) on  [Case].[RequestedProcedure1Id]=[RequestedProcedure1].[Id]
left outer join [Lookup] as RequestedProcedure2 with(nolock) on  [Case].[RequestedProcedure2Id]=[RequestedProcedure2].[Id]
...
left outer join [Lookup] as FamilyAsthma with(nolock) on  [Case].[FamilyAsthmaId]=[FamilyAsthma].[Id] 
left outer join [Lookup] as FamilyCancer with(nolock) on  [Case].[FamilyCancerId]=[FamilyCancer].[Id] 
left outer join [Contact] as ContactName with(nolock) on  [Case].[ContactId]=[ContactName].[Id] 
where [Case].[ApplicationName] = 'bodemo' And [Case].[Variation] = 'PRIMARY'
),
Case_Count as (select count(*) as 'TotalCount' from Case_Entries with(nolock)) select Case_Entries.*,Case_Count.TotalCount from Case_Entries with (nolock),Case_Count with (nolock)
where DataRow Between  0  and  19 order by DataRow asc
```

example of requestedprocedure xml (the other ones are basically the same):

```
<PDS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PD>
    <CT>Extension</CT>
    <ET>Text</ET>
    <PN>Name</PN>
    <PO>1</PO>
    <CL>Twenty</CL>
    <PV xsi:type="xsd:string">Buttock Implant</PV>
    <IR>false</IR>
    <IV>true</IV>
    <PTS>
      <C>en</C>
      <V>Buttock Implant</V>
    </PTS>
    <PTS>
      <C>zh-CHS</C>
      <V>臀部植入</V>
    </PTS>
    <PTS>
      <C>th</C>
      <V>รากเทียม buttock</V>
    </PTS>
    <PTS>
      <C>ja</C>
      <V>臀部インプラント</V>
    </PTS>
  </PD>
</PDS>
```

So I'm wondering a few things about performance here:

- Are the xqueries written in a performant way or is there a better way?
- I read you can do xml indexing, will this make any difference in my example? And how do I implement it in my scenario (I'm a bit confused with online examples)
- Will adding a namespace make any difference?
- And what about an xml collection?

Comment: Did you have requirements that said, keep the information in an XML text rather than parsing that information and put it in a column of the appropriate type? Or is this a project that you got in your lap and you are faced with this situation?

Comment: I don't see much you can improve in terms of XQuery statements. AFAICT you can indeed improve XML querying by providing XML indices. That's what XML indices are made for. I am however of the opinion that keeping information in XML rather than shredding them to tables and columns is laziness. You'll get worse performance keeping that information in XML, rather than shredding it to SQL tables.

Comment: Namespaces won't make a difference.

Comment: When it comes to xml collections, read this on [*XML Schema Collections (SQL Server)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187856.aspx).

Comment: How many rows are there? What is the structure of "Lookup"? It might speed things up, if you use `CROSS APPLY` to get the XML shredded to table data (using `.nodes()`) and continue from there... But in this snippet it seems to read ever only one value out of different XML. Filtering/searching/sorting after values *within* XML is - especially if there are many rows  - really hard work.